# How to parse a boolean from a JSON response in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How to parse a boolean from a JSON response in React?

Example of JSON response:

```
{
  awaiting_status: false,
  batch: 1,
  email_exists: true,
  receipts: ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the API code as well.Is it fetch/axios . ?

Comment: how to parse boolean? do you mean how to get email_exists,awaiting_status value from response?

Comment: `Example response` is not even remotely JSON - in JSON, all keys are enclosed in `"` ... and whetever that rubbish `(2)` is before the receipts array has to go - first step in parsing JSON is making sure your server sends JSON

Comment: "do you mean how to get email_exists,awaiting_status value from response"? - Yes, I want to display on UI email exists if the value is true for email_exists

Comment: @MonalisaDebnath I added answer, hope it will work as per the expectation. Thanks.

Comment: @MonalisaDebnath I'm curious to know if you figured out what you needed. Let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but react uses JSX which is JavaScript and XML so JSON is native in ReactJS.

https://codepen.io/jeremu/pen/MVGdWP

```
const myJson = {
  awaiting_status: false,
  batch: 1,
  email_exists: true,
  receipts: ["test1", "test2"]
};

function EmailMessage(props) {
  return myJson && myJson.email_exists
    ? 'Yes, yes it does.'
    : 'No. Check back later';
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Does Email Exist?</h1>
      <EmailMessage />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Will return ... Yes, yes it does

Comment: To be clear

      return myJson && myJson.email_exists
      ? 'Yes, yes it does.'
      : 'No. Check back later';  

Is the equivalent of 

      if (myJson && myJson.email_exists) {
        return 'Yes, yes it does.';
      } else {
        return 'No. Check back later';
      }

Answer (score 0):

You can do `const parsed = JSON.parse(response)`
Then you can access the values using parsed variable

(Data provided is not JSON BTW, There should not be `(2)` there)

Comment: and keys must be in `"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a JSON and not an Object, you can use

```
const parsed = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(parsed.awaiting_status) // bool true/false
const message = parsed.awaiting_status ? 'still pending' : 'retrieved'
```

Answer (score -1):

> I want to display on UI email exists if the value is true for email_exists

Use [JavaScript conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check the `email_exists` flag and based on that display in HTML.

```js
let obj = {
  awaiting_status: false,
  batch: 1,
  email_exists: true,
  receipts: ["test1", "test2"]
};

(obj.email_exists) ? document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = "Email Exist" : document.getElementById('email').innerHTML = "Email Not Exist"
```

```html
<div id="email">
</div>
```